# Where to put eventlisteners for serviceworker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, service-worker-events

Basicly I'm trying to accomplish to show a dialog when a new serviceworker version has been detected, and then to have user decide to reload to fetch it. To accomplish this we need to actively set `skipWaiting` before we reload window.

Here's my action:

```
  onClickHandler = () => {
    console.log('on click', 'posting skipWaiting');
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('skipWaiting');
  };
```

Here's my attempt to create the eventListener:

```
navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          console.log('worker state', installingWorker.state);
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed.'
              );

              navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
                console.log('skip waiting');
                if (event.data === 'skipWaiting') {
                  self.skipWaiting();
                }
              });
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
```

The issue is that `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event =>` does not get triggered. Am I declaring the listener wrong?

Comment: Your `console.log()` seems to have a missing quote at the end of `'tabs for this page are closed.`

Comment: It was a typo, I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You are close. In your installed block you can make a check for

`navigator.serviceWorker.controller`

If this exists it means that the old content will have been purged and the fresh content will have been added to the cache. Its a perfect time to display a message or to force a refresh.

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function (registration) {

                    $log.debug('The service worker has been registered ', registration);

                    if(navigator.online) {
                        toastr.warning('Offline Mode', 'Application Status');
                    }

                    // updatefound is fired if service-worker.js changes.
                    registration.onupdatefound = function () {
                        // The updatefound event implies that reg.installing is set; see
                        // https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#service-worker-container-updatefound-event
                        var installingWorker = registration.installing;

                        installingWorker.onstatechange = function () {
                            switch (installingWorker.state) {
                                case 'installed':
                                    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                                        // At this point, the old content will have been purged and the fresh content will
                                        // have been added to the cache.
                                        // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is available; please refresh."
                                        // message in the page's interface.
                                        toastr.info('Application has been updated, please refresh this page for the most recent version');

                                        window.location.reload();

                                        });
                                        caches.delete('scope-dynamic').then(function () {
                                            $log.debug('Killed the dynamic cache!');
                                        })
                                        $log.debug('New or updated content is available.');
                                    } else {
                                        // At this point, everything has been precached.
                                        // It's the perfect time to display a "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                                        toastr.success('Content is cached for offline use.', 'Application Status');
                                        $log.debug('Content is now available offline!');
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case 'redundant':
                                    $log.error('The installing service worker became redundant.');
                                    break;

                            }
                        };
                    };
                }).catch(function (e) {
                    $log.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
                });
```

There is some angular stuff sprinkled in there but that should help you get to where you wanna be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the code you provided has only defined receiving & sending messages from your client to the service worker.

The below method has defined a message to be sent to your controller (active) service worker.

```
onClickHandler = () => {
    console.log('on click', 'posting skipWaiting');
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('skipWaiting');
};
```

The definition below has added an event listener on your ServiceWorker container to receive any messages sent from the service worker.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
    console.log('skip waiting');
    if (event.data === 'skipWaiting') {
        self.skipWaiting();
    }
});
```

You now need to define the event handlers from the service worker file to receive & send messages.

In the service worker file, to receive messages from the client:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function handler (event) {
   console.log('skip waiting');
   if (event.data === 'skipWaiting') {
      self.skipWaiting();
   }
});
```

To send messages from serviceworker to your client:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  self.clients.matchAll().then(all => all.map(client => client.postMessage('data from webworker')));
});
```

You could also send data back from the serviceworker using a MessageChannel. On your client you would have to define something like below:

```
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(swUrl)
        .then(registration => {
            var messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
            // listener for messages from the ServiceWorker    
            messageChannel.port1.addEventListener('message', (event) => console.log(event.data)); 

            function sendMessage (message) {
                //send message to the active service worker
                navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(message, [messageChannel.port2]);
            }
      onClickHandler = () => {
          sendMessage('skipWaiting');
      };
   });
```

I found the below article to be quite helpful.

[ServiceWorker, MessageChannel & postMessage by Nicolás Bevacqua](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/serviceworker-messagechannel-postmessage)

Comment: Is it possible to listen for the `message` event inside the main JS thread?